# javax swing html parser not picking up img tags

Tags: java, html, swing, html-parsing

This HTML:

```
<td height="79" valign="top" width="70">
            <a href="http://e.livinghuntington.com/HS?a=stuff" target="_blank" title="Follow us on Twitter: http://twitter.com/#!/HuntingtonLive"> link link link <img alt="Follow us on Twitter: http://twitter.com/#!/HuntingtonLive" border="0" height="79" src="http://webe.emv3.com/livinghuntington/images/tt.png" style="display:block;" width="70"/></a>
        </td>
</table>
<table>
```

and this code:

```
public void handleStartTag(Tag tag, MutableAttributeSet attr, int pos) {

     System.err.println("tag = " + tag);
```

Gives this output:

```
tag = td
tag = a
tag = table
```

I tried various testing strategies:  if I nest a link (which I don't even know if is valid html) it correctly picks up the inner link.  If I pull the image out of the link it still doesn't pick up the img.  As far as I can tell it never picks up image tags at all.  Is there an error in code or a kludge or is this an irreparable problem with the HTML Parser (so I need to chuck it and use a new one)?

Comment: That's your question? What gives? Java's HTMLEditorKit is not perfect -actually not close to perfect, that's what gives

Comment: Can it pick up any other self closing tag?  Try `<img>` without the / at the end.

Comment: Nope.  fails on all 4 combinations of self-closing/open-close, and with img/src set.  It picks up tag = a on <a />.  I noticed that it fails to handle the text on <a> and handles it correctly on <a href="http://abc.com">, which seems consistent with @ControlAltDel's comment that it's kind of a crap parser.  Perhaps my img tags aren't good enough for it to pick up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was img is simple tag so is not picked up under startTag().  handleSimpleTag() is the handler to use.